# react native: empty state when try to fetch

Tags: react-native

I'm new in react native and I guess that probably miss something very simple but I read many previous questions and did not get my answer. I'm trying to fetch POST request with my data that I can render or print in the console exactly before the fetch function but when it sent the data it is null on the server. If I try with hardcore values directly into the fetch function it works well.

```
export default class CreateNewPostScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      source: '',
      description: '',
      location: '',
      token: ''
    }
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Create New Post'
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken").then((value) => {
      this.setState({
        //Getting data from prev screen(ProfileScreen)
        source: this.props.navigation.state.params.newPostBase64Image,
        token: value
      })
    }).done()
  }

  _fetchCreateNewPost = async () => {
    fetch(baseUrl + 'api/profile/CreateNewPost',{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: this.state.token
          },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          Date: new Date(),
          Description: this.state.description,
          Location: this.state.location,
          SourcePath: this.state.source
      }),
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <View style={styles.agreementField}>
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles.escBtn} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}>X</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._fetchCreateNewPost}>
              <Text style={styles.acceptBtn}>✓</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={{padding:5}}>
            <Image
              style={styles.image}
              source={{uri:`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.source}`}}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.textAreaContainer} >
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textArea}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              placeholder="Type something"
              placeholderTextColor="grey"
              numberOfLines={1}
              multiline={true}
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({description:text})}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View>
          <View>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Location"
                underlineColorAndroid= '#C0C0C0'
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({location:text})}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the body must be a JSON, not a string. JSON.stringify() returns a string.

I think you must change your code to this(some other things I changed):

Your `_fetchCreateNewPost` function:

```
_fetchCreateNewPost = () => {
  return fetch(baseUrl + 'api/profile/CreateNewPost',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: this.state.token
    },
    body: {
      Date: new Date(),
      Description: this.state.description,
      Location: this.state.location,
      SourcePath: this.state.source
    },
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

`onPress` of `TouchableOpacity` that uses `_fetchCreateNewPost`:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this._fetchCreateNewPost()}>
  <Text style={styles.acceptBtn}>✓</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: When change it like this I receive "unsupported BodyInit type" and my others screens use JSON.stringify() and work well

Comment: keep using `JSON.stringify()` and apply my other changes

Comment: I'm trying to transfer image as base64 string format in SourcePath, is this possibly the problem ? Because the string is too long